# Nginx conditionally allow all to react sub-route based on IP

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

I'm setting up an NGINX server and need to configure it to allow only certain IPs access to the root of a react application, but allow all to a certain subfolder (react route). Basically I need to allow all traffic to /sub/ but only a handful of IPs to the home directory /.
I tried

```
    location /sub/* { allow all;}
        
location / {
    allow x.x.x.x;
    deny all;}
```

but was getting a 403 error when using any other IP address except the 'x.x.x.x'.
What's the correct way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Remove the asterisk from `location /subdir/* { ... }`

Comment: Thanks. I did that, but got a 404 from x.x.x.x and 403 externally

Comment: Usually it means you don't have an index file under the requested path. And it isn't related with `allow`/`deny` directives. You'd better get your site fully workable before setting up the access rules. If you want just to show directory contents without the index file, use `autoindex on;` directive.

Comment: You're right, Ivan. It's actually a react application, and there're several locations under /subdir/ (such as /subdir/test/, /subdir/local/, etc), that's why I had the asterisk before.

Comment: nginx does not have such a syntax. The two most used location types are the prefix location `location /some/path { ... }` which match **any** request starting with `/some/path` and the regex matching location `location ~ <regex> { ... }`. Read the [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) to find more about the other location types. React application means every request other than the asset request should go to `index.html` where the route processing should be handled? Than you are trying to solve your task in a completely wrong way.

Comment: What you a trying to allow with your config, an access to some physical directory or some react app route rendering result?

Comment: I'm trying to allow access to a react app route /subdir/ and limit access to the root /.

Comment: So why you didn't mention it in your question? Your working configuration most likely relies on `try_files` directive? Why you didn't mention this too? Add your full config to your question (of course you can replace private information like real domain name, real root directory path etc. with some fake data)

Comment: And you'd better to rename your question if it isn't a subdirectory but a react app route.

Comment: Thanks, Ivan. I've never worked with Nginx before, and vaguely familiar with React, so this is new to me. I just want to know the syntax for limiting access to the root folder while granting public access to a sub-route. I've edited the question.

Comment: Your current config (which you don't add to your question even after been asked to do it) use nginx directive `try_files`, something like `try_files $uri /index.html;`, in the default location block, am I right? Do you understand what does it means and how is it works? Did you at least check any of nginx documentation? Do you understand that all the react app routes are some "virtual" paths and all the corresponding web pages are rendered by the main `index.html` file (at least in most cases)? (to be continued in the next comment)

Comment: That is exactly the reason you've got a 404 error after declaring an additional `location` block. NGINX doesn't send that route request to the main `index.html` file anymore, instead it tries to find an index file in a non-existent folder. Your approach could work if you'd have a regular site, not the react app based one. And once again, why didn't you add your `location / { ... }` block content to your question even after being asked to do so? Why should I guess what your configuration is look like?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224012/discussion-between-obi-e-and-ivan-shatsky).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you can try to do:

```
map $uri $disallow_by_route {
    ~^/subroute/    ""; # allow /subroute/... for all
    default         1;
}

map $remote_addr $disallow {
    x.x.x.x         ""; # some allowed IP
    y.y.y.y         ""; # another allowed IP
    default         $disallow_by_route;
}

server {
    ...
    location / {
        if ($disallow) { return 403; }
        ...
    }
}
```

However if your allowed pages used some assets (js, css, images etc.) from some other path than `/subroute/...` this config won't let them to load on restricted IPs. You can try to allow them checking the value of HTTP `Referer` header with a more complex `map` blocks chain:

```
map $http_referer $disallow_by_referer {
    # use a regex for your actual domain here
    ~^https?://example\.com/subroute/   "";
    default                             1;
}

map $uri $disallow_by_route {
    ~^/subroute/    "";
    # list all the other possible assets extensions (png, gif, svg, webp etc.) here
    ~\.(?:js|css)$  $disallow_by_referer;
    default         1;
}

map $remote_addr $disallow {
    x.x.x.x         ""; # some allowed IP
    y.y.y.y         ""; # another allowed IP
    default         $disallow_by_route;
}

server {
    ...
    location / {
        if ($disallow) { return 403; }
        ...
    }
}
```

Please note that this solution won't work if your server configuration (or react app itself) sets the referer policy to `no-referer`.